# "Every Sunday, he has lunch in restaurant" or "...a restaurant"?

Tags: indefinite-article

> A. Every Sunday, he has lunch in restaurant.
>
> B. Every Sunday, he has lunch in ***a*** restaurant.

Which of above sentences is correct? I want to tell the habit, not to specify any restaurant.

Comment: *Restaurant* is a countable noun, so it has to be *in a restaurant*.  Whether it's a habit or not, or a specific restaurant or not, doesn't make any difference; *restaurant* is a countable noun so it needs an article.

Comment: @stangdon, "*so it has to be in a restaurant. Whether it's a habit or not, or a specific restaurant*", I don't agree about that part. when we speak about a specific restaurant, we should use the definite article not the indefinite one.

Comment: @Abbasi - What I mean is that you have to use an article whether you mean "one specific restaurant" or "any restaurant".  But I could see saying "he has lunch in a restaurant" even if you mean a specific one.  For example, "Every Sunday he has lunch in a restaurant.  You know the little Greek one by the seaport?  That's the one."

Comment: No I don't know that little Greek one.

Answer (score 4):

I understand your confusion: You want to say he does this every week, but not necessarily at any specific restaurant.  It's just a *habitual* practice.

Even in this case, some determiner is necessary, and "a" works well because it is *indefinite* -- it could mean the same restaurant week after week, although it strongly *implies* that he eats at different restaurants.

Other examples:

> Every morning on her walk through her neighborhood, she picks up a newspaper from **a shop**.
>
> I like to stop by **a coffee shop** on my way to work.
>
> Every year at Christmas he steps into **a pub** to toast the Queen's health.

If you want to be more definite about where he eats, you would use "the" to specify a restaurant.

> Every Sunday he has lunch at **the** restaurant on the corner.
>
> Every Sunday he has lunch at **the** ELL Cafe.

On the other hand, if you want to be clear he does different restaurants each week, use "some".

> Every Sunday he has lunch at **some** restaurant.

Or, if you want to imply he doesn't care which and just picks a restaurant each time, use "any":

> Every Sunday he has lunch at **any** restaurant.

Comment: Your view is fine to me but we don't have to use some article in that sentence and nor is it necessary. We could use *my* which is not an article, instead of *a*.

Comment: Yeah, it may be like spitting hairs but with that comment I hoped that you changed the word *article* to *determiner*. That was all.

Answer (score 2):

Use "a": *Every Sunday he has lunch in a restaurant.*

Native speakers will often say "at a restaurant" rather then "in a restaurant".  They mean basically the same, and both are common.  The one potential difference is that "in a restaurant" would technically exclude eating the restaurant's food at their outside patio.

Answer (score 2):

> “Every Sunday, he has lunch in restaurant” or “…a restaurant”?
>   Which of above sentences is correct?

Only the latter.
The reason is that the word *restaurant* is a singular countable noun, and, we must use some type of determiners for it. Of course there are exceptions as well.
We have generally (to me) 4 kinds of determiners which one of them is the articles. Here we have some choices but the indefinite article is to be used here (since you haven't supply any further context).

Answer (score 2):

**In your example, the correct sentence(s) is(are):**

- “Every Sunday, he has lunch in a restaurant.”  **CORRECT**

**OR**

- “Every Sunday, he has lunch at a restaurant.”  **CORRECT**

---

**BUT YOU SHOULD ALSO NOTE:**

It is worth mentioning that if the speaker was talking about a specific restaurant, it would be correct to use  ".... in {restaurant 1}" or ".... at {restaurant 2}."

This is the case, even if they are countable, such as with brand named chain restaurants.  In these specific cases you may use either example correctly.  The brand or chain is treated as one specific, non-countable location [noun] (even though there are actually many restaurants, there is just one brand).

**FOR EXAMPLE:**

- “Every Sunday, he has lunch in McDonald's.”  **CORRECT**
- “Every Sunday, he has lunch in a McDonald's.”  **CORRECT**
- “Every Sunday, he has lunch at McDonald's.”  **CORRECT**
- “Every Sunday, he has lunch at a McDonald's.”  **CORRECT**

OR

- "Each week, he works at Walmart full-time."  **CORRECT**
- "Each week, he works at a Walmart full-time."  **CORRECT**

---

I know this may seem a bit confusing and contradictory, but hey, welcome to the English language!  It is always contradicting its own rules and has many exceptions to them.

Which is why I thought I would mention this specific "exception to the rule" while you were learning "the rule" [to place "a" before countable nouns] itself.

**Good luck with your studies.  Cheers!**